# How to check if a point (int - Coordinates) is within the hypotenuse of a triangle

Tags: geometry, collision-detection

I've got a right triangle and I want to check if a given point is on the Hypotenuse of that triangle. All points are plain integers, not floating-point variables.

(broken image, original location `https://tape.bplaced.net/dl/example2.png`)

*Edit:*
All green squares would be on the hypotenuse, the white squares not. I know x, y, the Coordinates of the Corners and the Coordinates of the Point I want to test.
All Coordinates are whole numbers (y is a little bit off in the drawing, sorry).

Comment: What do you mean "on the hypotenuse"?  From this example, I'd say anything within the bounds of the box described by the triangle would qualify.  Can you add some points that aren't "on the hypotenuse".

Comment: @raphaelr: Your image  404'd.

Comment: @raphealr: Nah, 403 this time. Can you upload to a well-known image host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work:

You know the triangle, so just create the function for the hypothenuse, in your example it would be `y = 5x/12`. If you now get a point, say `x = 6, y = 3`, you can use these variables to see if it comes out right: `3 = roundup(5*6/12)`. If it does, the point is on the triangle, if not - then not.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases to handle: one where the hypotenuse is vertical and the other where it is not.

For the vertical case, you just check if the point in question has a y value in the range of the hypotenuse.

For the non-vertical case, derive the equation of the hypotenuse using its endpoints.  The equation of a line is y = mx + b where m is the slope which is dx/dy.  Then b = y - mx.

Now that you have m and b, see if a candidate point's x and y satisfy the equation (does the point's y equal m * x + b ?).

However, practically, you should check for nearness instead of exact equality so check if the point's y is within some small delta of (m * x + b).

Answer (score 0):

I'll start doing this:

```
points = an array;
delta=y/x
acc = 0
j = 0
for (i=0;i<x;i++){
  points.push(i, j)
  acc+=delta
  while (acc > 1){
     acc-=1
     j++
     points.push(i,j)
  }
}
```

And then you have all the points in the hypotenuse. There are better algorithms for drawing lines, but this could be a start.